# Email tracking by google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am using following code for tracking emails opened.

`var tracking_url = encodeURI('http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-66604xxx-1&cid='+client_id+'&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&el='+emailAddress+'&cs=newsletter&cm=email&cn=Referral&cm1=1');`

Which results in 
`http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-66604xxx-1&cid=63681169&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&el=secretemail@secretemail.in&cs=newsletter&cm=email&cn=Referral&cm1=1`

And pass this value by javascript like this `'<img src="'+tracking_url+'" />'`

And gmail the output is this

`<img src="https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/yKWjuqq9fnjMaHMSqTLQwRvro_GdxobvmNO67ldPoBLI8_Ssnk3WIOWDbu9EX7Qb4RNvTA95hOKhTZMk3K2toUdUMduZIUijCFcKL1vRXEFHffwXIZX41I1ZfbZBJ445sDAS8gygd8hs2428fyTHwmBboCwDY2-WpYQ9yFwq1h-0EMoHLcxkXJ9mX-BOW3TMcSpmTIFa-cl-Thj7JLBqU2Dg-2RsnA9hf9ecZf8YTKtJ_D1PumKa1rw=s0-d-e1-ft#http://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&amp;tid=UA-66604xxx-1&amp;cid=1696011369&amp;t=event&amp;ec=email&amp;ea=open&amp;el=secretemail@secretemail.in&amp;cs=newsletter&amp;cm=email&amp;cn=Referral&amp;cm1=1" class="CToWUd">`

But In my analytics panel nothing is getting reflected

Comment: `el=secretemail@secretemail.in` - I hope you are not collecting email addresses as that is a violation of Google's privacy policy and terms of usage.

Answer (score 0):

[Google serves images in Gmail through a proxy server](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2013/12/images-now-showing.html). When the email is opened it calls the proxyed version (which in effect works like a cache), not the url that would send a hit to the GA server. I think other webmail clients behave similarly by now, so tracking opened e-mail via [web bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_beacon) is less then reliable now.